# Adding item to the Desktop context menu in Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, desktop

I want to add an item into the Desktop context menu (the menu you see when you right-click on an empty space on the Windows Desktop).

Something like Catalyst Control Center in this screenshot:
[image: Embedded Example]

I know how to add items to files' and folders' context menus through registry, but the Desktop seems to work differently: I didn't even find the text in the registry.

So, how can I add a new item into the Desktop menu and how can I associate some code with it?
I think the solution is language independent, if it's not, I'd appreciate any code that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Such a handler must be registered in HKCR\Directory\Background, instead of usual locations like HKCR\Directory, HKCR\Folder, etc.

Check out [Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

There's a series of articles on CodeProject that details writing Shell Extensions and is very good:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx