# Add to Windows Shell Extension Context Menu

Tags: .net, windows, windows-shell-extension-menu

I have read these:

[Adding item to the Desktop context menu in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553/adding-item-to-the-desktop-context-menu-in-windows)

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169474

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776852(VS.85).aspx

But I cannot find an **up-to-date** and straightforward piece of information on how to create a context menu item.

I'm sure it's in msdn somewhere, but I can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions) on TSS.

Comment: I'm having trouble with:

"You make sure that the .BATCHRESULTS node exists in the registry’s HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) node. If it doesn’t exist, you create it and set its default value to an arbitrary string—typically, BatchResultsFile. Next, you create a new entry under HKCR and name it after this arbitrarily chosen string. The BatchResultsFile node will contain the details of the shell configuration for .BATCHRESULTS files. "

When I do the second part, it says that it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [samples in All-In-One Code Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621025147/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx).