# How to customize windows default right click pop-up menu

Tags: c++, windows, popup

I have two questions. My first one is, that how can i "put" something into the default windows right click pop-up menu? I mean, if i click with the right mouse button on an .exe, then the default things appers(like cut, copy, send to, run as...), but how can i put there one extra line, like "MyApp", which will start my application? I want to do all this in c++.
My second question is, how can i get the filename (or the full path) on which i have started MyApp from the pop-up menu?

Thank in advance!

kampi

Comment: which will start my application in c++? Please rephrase. This does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I corrected it :) Hope you'll understqad it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Sounds like you're looking to simply alter or add to the context menu that is provided by Windows Explorer. It's really just a matter of registry settings. [See here for a good example](http://smallvoid.com/article/explorer-context-menu.html).

2) If you follow the zip example of the link above you'll see that the path to the target file is passed to the zip application. Your application, if it accepts arguments can similarly get the path to the file that is being open.

Comment: Basicly want i want is this. I go to c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ and on the iexplore.exe i right click, and start MyApp. But i need to get the above path, because MyApp will use it. So do you know how could i get it?

Comment: See my modification of #2. Might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check this stackoverflow post: [Adding item to the Desktop context menu in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553/adding-item-to-the-desktop-context-menu-in-windows)

> Such a handler must be registered in HKCR\Directory\Background, instead of usual locations like HKCR\Directory, HKCR\Folder, etc.
>
> [Check out Creating Shell Extension Handlers in MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067(VS.85).aspx)
>
> There's a series of articles on CodeProject that details writing Shell Extensions and is very good:
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx