# How can i add an item in the desktop right click menu in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, registry, contextmenu

I want to have an entry in the desktop background right click.

I have tried by editing the registry value. When I googled, I got some idea that we have to put the entry in "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell"

So, I have created the following keys in registry:

- 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Notepad' with value 'Notepad'
- 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Notepad\command' with value 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe'

When I tried it in windows7 it is working properly.

but it is not working in windows xp

can anyone help me sort out the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/76553/293712

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a shell extension handler for this and then add it to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background. 
Check this article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28VS.85%29.aspx

Extension, you write, should be a shortcut menu handler.